# Can anyone give a better understanding of this piece of code?

Tags: ros, c++, node-handle, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a question regarding the following lines in the node given [here](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) :

```
class ImageConverter
{
  ros::NodeHandle nh_;
  image_transport::ImageTransport it_;

........
.......

public:
 ImageConverter()
    : it_(nh_)
  {
.....
....
}
```

I know that the constructor is assigning the value of `nh_` to `it_`, but are they not variables of different type? If they are not, how can we know that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241501/can-anyone-give-a-better-understanding-of-this-piece-of-code?/) by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2016-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The constructor is not **assigning** to `it_`; it's invoking the constructor for `it_` and passing `nh_` as the argument to that constructor.

In general, the C++ initializer list syntax calls the constructor for each item. (and for scalar types construction is the same as assignment)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-08-10**:
Oh okay. Now I get it. Thank You.